# How to print to Python terminal with Boost::Python

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost

I would like to do the equivalent of a print in python from a library I wrote in C++. I am using Boost 1.60.0 and Python 2.7.

I found the following sites :[Mantid](http://www.mantidproject.org/Boost_Python_Introduction) and [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C%2B%2B). From what I understood this code should work, but nothing is printed.

**cpp file**

```
void greet()
{
    std::cout<<"test_01\n";
    std::cout<<"test_02"<<std::endl;
    printf("test_03");
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonIntegration)
{
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

**py file**

```
import PythonIntegration
PythonIntegration.greet()
```

I checked if the function was called by making it return something and it works, but still nothing is printed.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hello world example seems to do exactly what you want  : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C%2B%2B

Basically...

C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void say_hello(const char* name) {
    cout << "Hello " <<  name << "!\n";
}

#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    def("say_hello", say_hello);
}
```

Now, in setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name="PackageName",
    ext_modules=[
        Extension("hello", ["hellomodule.cpp"],
        libraries = ["boost_python"])
    ])
```

Now you can do this :

```
python setup.py build
```

Then at the python command prompt :

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.say_hello("World")
Hello World!
```

Comment: Quite right.   Your example is very similar to the hello world example here... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html

Comment: You are not really concerned about it calling your function(which it is), you are more worried/concerned about redirecting c++'s stdout back into python and printing it from python?

Comment: See edits to my answer.   Sorry about that first answer.

Comment: I have seen this example but I don't know what to do with the setup.py. I'll look into it. Thank you.